# How do I set a path variable on mac for another drive

Tags: macos, terminal, path

If I set the path variable to something on the drive like

```
export PATH=$HOME/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

then it works but if I want to set to another drive like

```
export PATH=/Volumes/MacHD/Developer/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

then it is not recognized.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `/Volumes/MacHD/Developer/flutter/bin` exists?

Comment: Yes I dropped the directory over the terminal and this is what populated